# Error while writing custom DynamoDB query in springBoot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query *dynamoDB* table `ProductInfo` based on a field `cost`.

When I am executing

```
aws dynamodb execute-statement --statement "SELECT * FROM ProductInfo WHERE cost='1000'" --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000"
```

from **cli**, I am getting correct output but when I am trying from *springboot* I am getting the error

> "AmazonDynamoDBException: Can not use both expression and
> non-expression parameters in the same request"

For project configuration I have followed this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-dynamodb)

My repository looks like below:

```
import org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.EnableScan;
import org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

@EnableScan
public interface ProductInfoRepository extends CrudRepository<ProductInfo, String> {

  @Query(fields = "select * from ProductInfo where cost = :cost")
  List<ProductInfo> findAllProductByCost(@Param("cost") String cost);
}
```

Comment: Hi - DId you manage to get a response on this issue?